# Crash on getting process name for file read access in miniflter

Tags: c, windows, kernel, minifilter

The system crashed with ERROR CODE as **PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED AREA** when trying to get the process name for any file read access. The code works great for some time. It's approx 30 mins. When spyShelter runs then the crash happens.

I am not able to figure it out. Please have a look and looking forward to hearing soon from you all the experts.

**Code:**

```
NTSTATUS GetProcessImageName(
    PEPROCESS eProcess,
    PUNICODE_STRING* ProcessImageName
)
{
    NTSTATUS status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    ULONG returnedLength;
    HANDLE hProcess = NULL;

    PAGED_CODE(); // this eliminates the possibility of the IDLE Thread/Process

    if (eProcess == NULL)
    {
        return STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER_1;
    }

    status = ObOpenObjectByPointer(eProcess,
        0, NULL, 0, 0, KernelMode, &hProcess);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("ObOpenObjectByPointer Failed: %08x\n", status);
        return status;
    }

    if (ZwQueryInformationProcess == NULL)
    {
        UNICODE_STRING routineName = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"ZwQueryInformationProcess");

        ZwQueryInformationProcess = (QUERY_INFO_PROCESS)MmGetSystemRoutineAddress(&routineName);

        if (ZwQueryInformationProcess == NULL)
        {
            DbgPrint("Cannot resolve ZwQueryInformationProcess");
            status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
            goto cleanUp;
        }
    }

    /* Query the actual size of the process path */
    status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess,
        ProcessImageFileName,
        NULL, // buffer
        0,    // buffer size
        &returnedLength);

    DbgPrint("\n\nMiniPreRead: kernelToUserMode: ProcessNameLength: %u\n", returnedLength);
    
    if (returnedLength >= 260) {
        DbgPrint("ZwQueryInformationProcess status = %x\n", status);
        status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
        goto cleanUp;
    }

    if (STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH != status) {
        DbgPrint("ZwQueryInformationProcess status = %x\n", status);
        status = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
        goto cleanUp;
    } 

    *ProcessImageName = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(PagedPool, returnedLength, SPY_TAG);

    if (NULL == ProcessImageName) {
        status =  STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
        goto cleanUp;
    }

    status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess,
        ProcessImageFileName,
        *ProcessImageName,
        returnedLength,
        &returnedLength);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        ExFreePool(*ProcessImageName);
        *ProcessImageName = NULL;
    }
cleanUp:

    if (hProcess) {
        ZwClose(hProcess);
    }

    return status;
}
```

Thank you so much.

Now the stack shows **Line Number 702 of file minispy.c**

```
**STACK_TEXT**

FAILED_INSTRUCTION_ADDRESS: 
win32kbase!UserIsUserCritSecIn+0
ffffe54c`f35e0450 ??              ???

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffec87`2d597dd8 fffff805`57ca8d02 : ffffe54c`f35e0450 00000000`00000003 ffffec87`2d597f40 fffff805`57b1afe0 : nt!DbgBreakPointWithStatus
ffffec87`2d597de0 fffff805`57ca83f7 : ffffe54c`00000003 ffffec87`2d597f40 fffff805`57bd81f0 ffffec87`2d598480 : nt!KiBugCheckDebugBreak+0x12
ffffec87`2d597e40 fffff805`57bc3b97 : fffff805`57e641f8 fffff805`57cd2855 ffffe54c`f35e0450 ffffe54c`f35e0450 : nt!KeBugCheck2+0x947
ffffec87`2d598540 fffff805`57c13ae0 : 00000000`00000050 ffffe54c`f35e0450 00000000`00000010 ffffec87`2d598820 : nt!KeBugCheckEx+0x107
ffffec87`2d598580 fffff805`57acdcbf : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000010 00000000`00000000 ffffe54c`f35e0450 : nt!MiSystemFault+0x18f320
ffffec87`2d598680 fffff805`57bd1b5e : 00000000`00000240 00000000`00000240 00000000`00000000 ffffec87`2d598950 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x34f
ffffec87`2d598820 ffffe54c`f35e0450 : fffff807`cf85af9b ffffec87`2d598c30 ffffec87`2d598db0 00000000`00000020 : nt!KiPageFault+0x35e
ffffec87`2d5989b8 fffff807`cf85af9b : ffffec87`2d598c30 ffffec87`2d598db0 00000000`00000020 fffff807`cf86c772 : win32kbase!UserIsUserCritSecIn
ffffec87`2d5989c0 fffff807`cf85b8a9 : ffffec87`2d598c98 ffff9804`00000000 00000000`000047bb 00000000`00000000 : SpyShelter!SpS_GetProcessPathW+0x15eb
ffffec87`2d598a50 fffff805`5801b10d : ffffbf80`6bec0d00 ffffec87`2d598c98 ffffec87`2d598c98 ffffec87`00000000 : SpyShelter!SpS_GetProcessPathW+0x1ef9
ffffec87`2d598a80 fffff805`5802afa5 : 00000000`00000000 ffffec87`2d598c20 00000000`00000000 ffff9804`9229de80 : nt!ObpCallPreOperationCallbacks+0x10d
ffffec87`2d598b00 fffff805`5800774c : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff9804`998ed4c0 006e0069`00000000 : nt!ObpCreateHandle+0xab5
ffffec87`2d598d30 fffff805`5631104b : ffff9804`99d1bb50 00000000`10000004 ffffec87`2d599549 fffff805`57b1b02c : nt!ObOpenObjectByPointer+0xec
ffffec87`2d598f90 fffff805`56311321 : fffff805`56312c60 00000000`00000200 00000000`00000000 ffff9804`99d1bdb0 : minispy!GetProcessImageName+0x4b [C:\Users\jay\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\minispyNetworkShareBlock\filter\minispy.c @ 702]
ffffec87`2d5994a0 fffff805`5c5845d0 : ffffec87`2d599680 00000000`00000000 ffff9804`96fbbb03 00000000`00060900 : FLTMGR!FltpPerformPreCallbacks+0x2fd
ffffec87`2d5995b0 fffff805`5c584142 : 00000000`00000000 ffffec87`2d599680 ffff9804`96fbbb20 ffffec87`2d599690 : FLTMGR!FltpPassThroughInternal+0x90
ffffec87`2d5995e0 fffff805`5c583f2e : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 fffff805`580319a5 : FLTMGR!FltpPassThrough+0x162
ffffec87`2d599660 fffff805`57a467f9 : ffff9804`96fbbb20 00000000`00000200 00000000`00000000 ffffffff`80001ef8 : FLTMGR!FltpDispatch+0x9e
ffffec87`2d5996c0 fffff805`58029d65 : 00000000`00000000 ffff9804`9a12c990 ffff9804`9a12c9e0 ffff9804`9a12c990 : nt!IofCallDriver+0x59
ffffec87`2d599700 fffff805`58026cbf : ffff9804`00000000 ffff9804`9abda8e0 ffffec87`2d599af0 ffffec87`2d599980 : nt!IopSynchronousServiceTail+0x1a5
ffffec87`2d5997a0 fffff805`57bd5355 : 00000000`00000001 ffffffff`80001ef8 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtReadFile+0x59f
ffffec87`2d599890 fffff805`57bc78b0 : fffff805`57b28996 ffffbf80`744d7000 ffffffff`80002610 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
ffffec87`2d599a98 fffff805`57b28996 : ffffbf80`744d7000 ffffffff`80002610 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiServiceLinkage
ffffec87`2d599aa0 fffff805`580da37c : ffffbf80`744d7000 ffffec87`2d599c30 ffffbf80`00000000 ffffbf80`744d7000 : nt!CmpDoFileRead+0xb6
ffffec87`2d599b50 fffff805`58086ca4 : 00000000`00000030 ffffbf80`782e1000 ffffbf80`782e1000 ffffbf80`71f2cb90 : nt!CmpFileRead+0x2c
ffffec87`2d599ba0 fffff805`58084e5d : 00000000`00000030 ffffec87`2d59a3d0 ffffbf80`782e1000 ffffbf80`782e1000 : nt!HvpGetHiveHeader+0x7c
ffffec87`2d599be0 fffff805`58086e8c : ffffec87`2d599e60 01d714ee`4baa7a6a 00000000`00000001 ffffbf80`782e1000 : nt!HvLoadHive+0xa1
ffffec87`2d599d20 fffff805`580844ae : ffffffff`ffffffff ffffec87`2d599e60 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : nt!HvHiveStartFileBacked+0x100
ffffec87`2d599d60 fffff805`57fe2151 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000009c ffffec87`2d59a090 00000000`00000000 : nt!CmpCreateHive+0x62a
ffffec87`2d599f90 fffff805`58099833 : ffff9804`99bd93a0 fffff805`57a4e5b6 ffff9804`99bd9118 fffff805`57e63878 : nt!CmpInitHiveFromFile+0x3f9
ffffec87`2d59a1d0 fffff805`57fe2f10 : fffff805`57e63880 ffffec87`2d59a350 00000000`00000000 ffffec87`2d59a768 : nt!CmpCmdHiveOpen+0xd7
ffffec87`2d59a250 fffff805`57fe4ba5 : 00000000`00000000 ffffec87`00000010 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : nt!CmLoadAppKey+0x364
ffffec87`2d59a6a0 fffff805`57fe4331 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffff813d`8d0f6699 : nt!CmLoadDifferencingKey+0x869
ffffec87`2d59aa20 fffff805`57bd5355 : 00000000`00000620 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!NtLoadKeyEx+0x51
ffffec87`2d59aa90 00007ffe`ecb7ee04 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x25
000000a9`b57fe238 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffe`ecb7ee04
```

**LINE 702:**

```
status = ObOpenObjectByPointer(eProcess,
0, NULL, 0, 0, KernelMode, &hProcess);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
DbgPrint("ObOpenObjectByPointer Failed: %08x\n", status);
return status;
}
```

Comment: Can you load the memory dump in WinDbg and give us a stack trace?

Comment: @icebp I have added a link for the file. Please have a look at it. Many Many Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend against uploading dump files to public websites, they may contain sensitive information. Anyway, I can't debug your code for you. I don't have your source code, your debug symbols etc. You should learn to use WinDbg if you want to write Windows kernel code. Check [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/performing-kernel-mode-debugging-using-windbg) for resources on how to get started.

Comment: @icebp The problem is in this code only. When I use to get the process path the system crash with ERROR code PAGED_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA. If I don't use then-No no crash occurs. **ObOpenObjectByPointer** is used here.

Comment: Look at your dump file and ask yourself if there is any information there that would allow someone to access your system.  I second icebp's suggestion that posting that file is not a good idea.  Stick with detailed descriptions of relevant error messages, comments in code where you believe crash is occurring, and if it can be done, provide a [mcve].

Comment: @icebp I am an absolute beginner to kernel debugging & really sorry for it. The crash is occurring in this function only if the spyShelter also running.  If spyShelter doesn't run then there is no crash.

Comment: On the machine on which the BSOD happened, if you go to `C:\Windows\` you should see a `MEMORY.DMP` file. You can load that file in [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugger-download-tools](WinDbg) and inspect the crash. The first thing you will want to check is the stack (using the `kv` command). This will tell you exactly at what line the BSOD is triggered.

Comment: @icebp Sure. I am trying to check. I Will let you know once done.

Comment: @icebp I have added STACK_TEXT and LINE NUMBER 702 is the problem. I don't understand what the problem? Can you please have a look?

Comment: Opening the dump in windbg will also show you details like the address you tried to access when the fault happened. I can't stress how important it is for you to get familiar with WinDbg if you do kernel development. You must make an effort and learn to use the tool and debug these crashes.

Answer (score 0):

IRP_MJ_READ Operation callback routine was often called at DISPATCH_LEVEL.
But ObOpenObjectByPointer function must be called at ACP_LEVEL or lower, according to  [WDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-obopenobjectbypointer)

I suggest you get and save the process name in IRP_MJ_CREATE operation callback, and use it in IRP_MJ_READ Operation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I try it and let you know. This crash only happens if the "SpyShelter" software is running along with. If SpyShelter is disabled or uninstalled then no crash happens. Some say there is a bug in SpyShelter.